# Why the user needs to request admin approval in Azure Single Sign On after he is added to users list?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, single-sign-on

[image]

I created an SSO application in the azure portal. As a global administrator I signed to my application with sso and I'm able to fetch the access token and graph details.

In our organization we need to allow few users to use this application. So I added their emails to the 'Users and Groups' in Azure portal. So When the users signed in,they allowed the consent permissions and then the below window appears. May I know the reason?

- Is this normal or any kind of bug from side?
- Is this window appear everytime once the user got approval ?

Please help me to solve this as I am going through a tough time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is not a bug and it is Admin Consent. You as a global
   Administrator need to approve the concern from azure AD.
2. This window will appear only once and it will not appear once user log-in after consent next time.

Please go through [Ms Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-admin-consent-workflow#how-users-request-admin-consent) which has information of configuring Admin Consent.

Comment: Are you sure ? So if there are 100 users in the group, as a global administrator I need to approve everyone like that ?

Comment: Hi @Debugger, Admin consent work flow helps end users a way to request access to applications that require admin consent. If you consent the application permissions already then you will not face any problem in consenting all other users. Please check the document I have shared for more information.

Comment: As per the document 'Admin consent requests(preview)' is same for me.

Brother, what does this means "If you consent the application permissions already then you will not face any problem in consenting all other users." ?

As a global administrator when I logged in the app 'Permission Requested' screen appeared and I enable the permission.

Comment: Hi @Debugger, Once you will approve.It will approve for the app. All other users can access it.

Comment: Hi Hari,
Can you share your email-id ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to use application permissions, since both shown permissions do not require admin consent for delegated permissions scenarios.

You can read about permission types at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#permission-types

If you want to review the configuration of your application you can turn to Azure AD. On page https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationMenuBlade/CallAnAPI/appId/YOURAPPID/isMSAApp/ (replace YOURAPPID with your app id) you should see something similar to this:

[image]

If you at (1) have any of type "Application", these will require admin consent.

Regardless of whether you have any of such, you (required admin privileges) can grant application consent for the tenant using the button at (2).